# Can't get this unit test (on a helper) to run without exceptions - AngularJS, Karma, Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm new to Angular and Karma and every site out there seems to recommend a different way of writing unit tests, which makes all of this very confusing. Help is appreciated!

I have a helper class that has a dependency on a service class. I am writing a unit test for the helper class. I have this:

```
module("myModule");

    it('works!', inject(function(myHelper) {

        module(function($provide) {
            $provide.service('myService', function() {
                payload = spyOn(myService, 'getPayload').andReturn(
                    {id: 1 });
                });
        });


        expect(myHelper.getSomeData()).toEqual(exepectedData);
    }));
```

The exception I'm getting when running the test is:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: myHelperProvider <- myHelper
```

I've tried all different ways of doing this, but haven't gotten it to work yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `module("myModule");` in a `beforeEach`, i.e.:

```
beforeEach(module('myModule'));
```

You *may* have luck with actually *calling* the function returned by `module("myModule")`, i.e.:

```
module("myModule")();
```

... but have never tried this and I have serious doubts.

Also I always enclose my `it()` specs in a `describe()` block; not sure if strictly necessary though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added that beforeEach and no luck. Also, I do have a describe block. I just didn't show that.